# Attempt to invoke virtual method Model.WebSite.getSources()' on a null object reference at .Adapter.ListSourceAdap

Tags: java, android-studio

I dont know where did I define a null object on this one please help me find out ! It look like Im trying to use a null object from Website and pass it to ListSourceAdapter but I dont know why where and how to fix it, please help me out.

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.example.nutshell.myapplication.Model.WebSite.getSources()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.nutshell.myapplication.Adapter.ListSourceAdapter.getItemCount(ListSourceAdapter.java:106)
```

ListSourceAdapter (Where I pass the getSource() )

```
     class ListSourceViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
{
    ItemClickListener itemClickListener;
    TextView source_title;
    CircleImageView source_image;

    public ListSourceViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

    source_image=(CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.source_image);
    source_title=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.source_name);

    }
public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener)
{
    this.itemClickListener=itemClickListener;
}
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        itemClickListener.onClick(v, getAdapterPosition(),false);
    }
}


public class ListSourceAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<ListSourceViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private WebSite webSite;
private IconBetterIdeaService mService;

    public ListSourceAdapter(Context context, WebSite webSite) {
        this.context = context;
        this.webSite = webSite;

    mService=Common.getIconService();

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ListSourceViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View itemView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.source_layout,parent,false);
        return new ListSourceViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ListSourceViewHolder holder, int position) {
    StringBuilder iconBetterAPI=new StringBuilder(" https://icons.better-idea.org/allicons.json?url=");
    iconBetterAPI.append(webSite.getSources().get(position).getUrl());
    mService.getIconUrl(iconBetterAPI.toString()).enqueue(new Callback<IconBetterIdea>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<IconBetterIdea> call, Response<IconBetterIdea> response) {
            if (response.body().getIcons().size() > 0)
            {
                Picasso.with(context)
                        .load(response.body().getIcons().get(0).getUrl()).into(holder.source_image);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<IconBetterIdea> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
    holder.source_title.setText(webSite.getSources().get(position).getName());
    holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {

            Intent intent=new Intent(context, ListNews.class);
            intent.putExtra("source",webSite.getSources().get(position).getId());
        }
    });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
      return webSite.getSources().size();
    }
}
```

and WebSite.java is:

```
public class WebSite {

    private String status;
    private List<Source> sources;

    public WebSite() {
    }

    public WebSite(String status, List<Source> sources) {
        this.status = status;
        this.sources = sources;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public List<Source> getSources() {
        return sources;
    }

    public void setSources(List<Source> sources) {
        this.sources = sources;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you create `ListSourceAdapter` instance. It is very likely that you did not initialize `webSite` variable

Comment: I did initialize it in the top of ListSourceAdapter.java

Comment: and if I did not how do I fix it ?

Comment: What I mean is how do you create its instance. Something like `ListSourceAdapter adapter = new ListSourceAdapter(yourContext, yourWebsite);`

Comment: I did that in a MainActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

In `getItemCount()` method, make sure `webSite` is properly initialized. For example

```
ListSourceAdapter adapter = new ListSourceAdapter(context, new Website());
```

Comment: does not fix it still crashed